# nssm + Selenium Server 3 + Windows 10: Behat tests are not launching Chrome

Tags: windows, nssm

I successfully installed nssm with the command: `PS C:\Users\MyUser> nssm install selenium-server java -jar "C:\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar`

Then I try to proceed to run my Behat tests, the tests appear to be running when I see the steps pass in the command line. Strangely, I do not see Chrome open up as the test progresses.

If I run selenium-server manually (without nssm), then I can see Chrome running the test fine.